# How to unit test FileStream's File.Open

Tags: c#, unit-testing

First of all, I'm familiar with the concept of Mocking for Unit Tests, and I'm writing an application according to TDD .

I do have a method, in which I need to read a file.
A File is read in:

```
 using (var webshopXmlFileStream = StreamFactory.Create(importFile))
 {
     // Opens a reader that will read the Xml file.
     using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(webshopXmlFileStream))
     {
         // Read the nodes "Node" and "ArticleGroup" recursively.
         var nodes = XmlReaderUtils.EnumerateAxis(reader, new[] { "Node", "ArticleGroup" });
     }
 }
```

Of course, this isn't unit test-able.

So, I've created an interface called `IStreamFactory` which has one single method:

```
Stream Create(string filePath);
```

The implementation of this interface looks like:

```
public Stream Create(string filePath)
{ 
  return File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None); 
}
```

So, now I can mock the interface to return a `MemoryStream`, like so:

```
const string webshopXmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                                "<Node>" +
                                  "<Name></Name>" +
                                "</Node>";
var streamFactoryMock = new Mock<IStreamFactory>();
streamFactoryMock.Setup(action => action.Create(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string input) => new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(webshopXmlData)));
```

The problem is when I'm unit testing the `reader` is `null` and no `nodes` are being returned in the application.

Anyone has an idea on what's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem here for testing is that you have a method that is doing two things:

1. Open and read the contents of a file.
2. Read the nodes you need from an XmlDocument.

What you probably really want to test here is that you get the expected set of nodes from a particular document.  If you split your method something like so, then it might be a bit easier to test, and you also then have a method with only a single responsibility.  You can unit test your loader class separately, and then check the logic in you xml node reading:

```
class
{   

    void LoadNodes(IFileLoader loader)
    {
         using(var reader = loader.GetReader()) 
         {
              var nodes = XmlReaderUtils.EnumerateAxis(reader, new[] { "Node", "ArticleGroup" });
         }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I've accepted this as an answer because you've touched a good point here, but the problem really lies in my Xml string. Therefore, the returned results were empty.